# OpenERP disable editing of field if in edit mode

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

We need to allow for a field in a view to be visible but not editable in edit mode. is this possible in OpenERP? if not can I at least hide it in edit mode?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is attribute readonly for this.
Example from `stock.view_production_lot_revision_form`:

```
<field name="author_id" readonly="1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

another way, you can set read only attribute in pyhton class. like that

'fieldName': fields.char('label name', size=300, readonly=True),